# ecr login from Jenkins returns unknown flag: --password-stdin

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to login to ecr to pull the image from Jenkins using

```
sh '''aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login
--username AWS --password-stdin <account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'''
```

But it returns

```
+ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1
+ docker login --username AWS --password-stdin {account-id}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
unknown flag: --password-stdin
See 'docker login --help'.
```

It is expecting some alternative for docker --password-stdin. Needed help in running this command from Jenkins for pulling the docker image from ecr. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `echo $(aws ecr get-authorization-token --region us-east-1 --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | cut -d: -f2) | docker login -u AWS https://541574621075.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --password-stdin`

Comment: I got `unknown flag: --password-stdin`   Here's what I got=>   `+ docker login -u AWS https://541574621075.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --password-stdin
++ aws ecr get-authorization-token --region us-east-1 --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken'`
++ base64 -d
++ cut -d: -f2
unknown flag: --password-stdin
See 'docker login --help'.
+ echo {a very big token ending with ==}

Comment: Please share docker version & awscli versions

Comment: Can I do `sh ''' docker login
--username AWS <account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --password $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1)'''`

Comment: Docker version is 19.03.13. aws-cli/1.19.5. Tried `sh ''' docker login
--username AWS <account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --password $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1)'''` It returned `Error response from daemon: pull access denied for id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/../, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again`.

Comment: Says your authentication expired and or that docker image you are trying to pull doesn't exist. Follow the push commands on `ECR` to login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

--password-stdin expects the password from standard input hence using the below code in jenkins script solved my problem!

```html
sh '''docker login -u AWS https://<<account-id>>.dkr.ecr.<<region>>.amazonaws.com -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1)'''
```

Comment: login works for me, but I get a token expiration almost instantaneously, unusable... thinking I will need to downgrade awscli to 1.x to use get-login again

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I result it by using the docker plugin instead of the command shown in AWS

Indeed, check this blog that allows you to connect to the AWS easily **&& Push or Pull the images from AWS ECR**
https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-push-a-docker-image-to-amazon-ecr-with-jenkins-ed4b042e141a